# R- choropleth maps- choroplethr package

Tags: r, google-maps, choropleth, choroplethr

Im trying to make a choropleth map of the european countries according to some metric (percentage of the population that have experienced an accident  at work) using the new choroplethr package. 
Here's a reproducible example to demonstrate the 2 problems I need to solve.

```
a<-c(4.1,2.5,0.4,6.4,1.4,1.8,3.8,1.3,2.3,8.4,5.2,1.9,0.8,1.5,2.1,1.2,3.8,1.4,3.1,0.8,4.0,1.3,4.8,2.6,2.8,2.3,3.1,2.5)
    target<-c("austria","belgium","bulgaria","switzerland","cyprus","czech republic","denmark",
"estonia","spain","finland","france","greece","croatia","hungary","ireland","italy",
"lithuania","luxembourg","latvia","norway","poland","portugal","romania","sweden",
"slovenia","slovakia","turkey","united kingdom")
datas<-data.frame(region=target,value=a)
datas$region<-as.character(datas$region)


install.packages("choroplethr")
install.packages("choroplethrMaps")
library(choroplethr);library(choroplethrMaps)
data(country.map)
data(country.regions)

country_choropleth(datas,legend="%",num_colors=1,zoom=target)
```

[image: whole europe]
1) The first profound problem that i come upon is these extra areas that belong to some countries(e.g france) and don't let the map zoom entirely on europe . 
I gave zoom parameter the whole vector of the countries that exist in the data frame .
if i tried to `country_choropleth(datas,legend="%",num_colors=1,zoom="switzerland")`
then it would zoom only on switzerland
[image: switzerland]
The problem arrives from countries such as france where 
`country_choropleth(datas,legend="%",num_colors=1,zoom="france")`
[image]

So i need a way to disengage the areas that belong to european countries and are not in the European area . Any ideas?

2) The second problem that i have is that inside `country.regions$region` where the available regions to be used with the package exist , malta is missing. Its a single blot on the map , but still i cant skip it . 
Is there any way to add a country ?

Comment: third you should prbly also make sure you're using the lambert azimuthal equal area coord system for the EU as suggested by the EU JRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably make this two questions. You can augment the output of the choropleth pkg with other `ggplot` layers/aesthetics. To "zoom in" and use close to a proper projection you can do:

```
library(ggplot2)

gg <- country_choropleth(datas,legend="%",num_colors=1,zoom=target)
gg <- gg + xlim(-31.266001, 39.869301)
gg <- gg + ylim(27.636311, 81.008797)
gg <- gg + coord_map("lambert", lat0=27.636311, lat1=81.008797)
gg
```

[image]

(and you can play with the bounding box coords to get in a bit tighter)\

Comment: Thank you for your help , it was easy in the end . Though it seems the result is more focused and better to my taste  without the last line . Could you give me a little briefing  about coord_map  and if there is any specific reason to use it ?  Thanks again

Comment: It's to change the projection. [This](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/4311134/4366152/Map-projections-EUROPE.pdf/460d90e4-b7f2-49b7-8962-5c860c76757d) is a good guidebook for Europe and (EU) projections. The choice of projection can have a dramatic effect on how a map is interpreted. You should absolutely use some `coord_map` so you have a fixed aspect ratio, but you should also choose a projection that makes sense and authentically represents the data.